# How to get a reference to a module inside the module itself?

Tags: python, self-reference

How can I get a reference to a module from within that module? Also, how can I get a reference to the package containing that module?

Comment: I suspect you might be asking this question because you have a variable in **module scope** (e.g., BLAH=10 outside a function or class), then a **class/function variable** named BLAH, and you want to differentiate.  A valid question here is: **Is this necessary?**  Scope rules are notoriously prone to mistake, especially by the 'idiot' who picks up your code after you (i.e., you, 6 months later).  Tricks like this are rarely necessary; I attempt to avoid them completely because they're so often confusing and wrongly modified later.

Comment: @KevinJ.Rice "the 'idiot' who picks up your code after you (i.e., you, 6 months later)" made my day!

Comment: Who cares why he is asking the question? There are plenty of valid reasons to need to do this.

Comment: @Christopher: Although the need doesn't often arise, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66712690/355230) a case in point.

Answer (score 262, accepted):

```
import sys
current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
```

Comment: except for this won't be quite correct if module is reloaded; I don't think there's any place where a reference is guaranteed to be kept, if there was, reloading wouldn't really work, right?

Comment: Reloading re-uses the same module object; no new module object is created, so it's still correct in the face of re-loading.

Comment: tks, only this answer works directly with module path with dots

Answer (score 29):

One more technique, which doesn't import the sys module, and arguably - depends on your taste - simpler:

```
current_module = __import__(__name__)
```

Be aware there is no import. Python imports each module only once.

Comment: This seems like a really nice way to avoid importing sys. Other than being a bit counter-intuitive to read are there any potential downsides to this approach?

Comment: @JeremyDouglass. Not that I'm aware of. __import__ is a legit, documented, built-in function (the only __xx__ function). You can replace it with the 'importlib' package (you'll have to import it). Maybe - never happened to me - you could have an issue with relative/absolute import, if a module with the same name is available in sys.path, in which case you can solve it with the 'level' argument of the function.

Comment: This solution does not work on my code. Instead of create a reference to the module, it creates a reference to the package.

Am I the only one to have this behavior ?

Comment: @sangorys - I too am seeing this behavior (getting a reference to the package instead of the module) on Python 3.9

Comment: Per the docstring: "When importing a module from a package, note that __import__('A.B', ...) returns package A when fromlist is empty, but its submodule B when fromlist is not empty."  It is also advised in the same place to use importlib.import_module instead, which does not have this behavior.

Comment: Do not use this answer, it will drive you nuts with unintuitive behavior like sometimes importing a higher up module than the one you specified. Details: stackoverflow.com/a/37308413/210867

Answer (score 17):

If you have a class in that module, then the `__module__` property of the class is the module name of the class. Thus you can access the module via `sys.modules[klass.__module__]`. This is also works for functions.

Answer (score 15):

You can get the name of the current module using `__name__`

The module reference can be found in the `sys.modules` dictionary.

See the Python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=__name__)

Answer (score 5):

According to [@truppo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1676860/687896) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21233334/687896) (and [PEP366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/)):

**Reference to "this" *module***:

```py
import sys
this_mod = sys.modules[__name__]
```

**Reference to "this" *package***:

```py
import sys
this_pkg = sys.modules[__package__]
```

> `__package__` and `__name__` are the same if from a (top) `__init__.py`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass it in from outside:

```
mymod.init(mymod)
```

Not ideal but it works for my current use-case.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to get access to module variable then use `globals()['bzz']` (or `vars()['bzz']` if it's module level).

Answer (score 0):

```
from importlib import import_module
current_module = import_module(__name__)
```

PS: see also [Sargera's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676835/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-module-inside-the-module-itself#comment127563907_45378845)