# Get current python module object (by name or otherwise)

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I wanted to get the current module, e.g. to reload it, I would do:

```
import sys
sys.modules[__name__]
```

Is there a better way to do this (e.g. not involving `__name__`)? Better in this context means more idiomatic, more portable, more robust, or more...any of the other things we usually desire in our software.

I use python 2, but answers for python 3 will no doubt be useful to others.

Comment: No, `sys.modules[__name__]` is *exactly* right.

Comment: You may want to read [PEP 395](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0395/), which describes all of the known traps/problems with `__name__`, and explains why there are no better alternatives that can avoid any of them in Python as it is today (3.4—and of course it's even _more_ true for 2.7). (Despite the title, it proposed a few related changes, not just adding `__qualname__`, like a special metapath hook to make `__main__` and the real module name act equivalent.)

Comment: @abarnert Awesome, very informative.

Comment: @sds In what way is this a duplicate? `globals()` is not the solution here.

Comment: @Marcin:  wrong link. this is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1676835/850781

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a reference to a module inside the module itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676835/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-module-inside-the-module-itself)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no more idiomatic method to get the current module object from `sys.modules` than what you used.

`__name__` is set by Python on import, essentially doing:

```
module_object = import_py_file(import_name)
module_object.__name__ = import_name
sys.modules[import_name] = module_object
```

so the `__name__` reference is *exactly* what you want to use here.