# What's the purpose of the "__package__" attribute in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

All I want to know is **what exactly does `__package__` mean**? Didn't find any explanation in the official doc, even on SO.

If you could provide some examples I would be very happy.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

See the [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) and [import system reference documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html):

> The major proposed change is the introduction of a new module level attribute, `__package__`. When it is present, relative imports will be based on this attribute rather than the module `__name__` attribute.

and

> - The module’s `__package__` attribute should be set. Its value must be a string, but it can be the same value as its `__name__`. If the attribute is set to `None` or is missing, the import system will fill it in with a more appropriate value. When the module is a package, its `__package__` value should be set to its `__name__`. When the module is not a package, `__package__` should be set to the empty string for top-level modules, or for submodules, to the parent package’s name. See [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) for further details.

So, for a module located in `foo/bar/baz.py`, `__name__` is set to `foo.bar.baz`, and `__package__` is set to `foo.bar`, while `foo/bar/__init__.py` will have `foo.bar` for both the `__name__` and `__package__` attributes.

Comment: Martijn, than you for your answer, but would you mind to give an example of the problem when the `__package__` attribute is really usefull?

Comment: @Andrei: the PEP I link to addresses this specifically, but it allows you to detect when a module file in a package is executed directly (with `python /modulename.py`) and adjust for that situation.

Comment: I was reading PEP but didn't quite understand how it would be used, mainly because the default behavior of the  `__name__.rpartition('.')[0]` line is not entirely clear to me, just as the interaction of the `__name__` and `__package__` attributes and the base paths used for importing module from other folders within project. In fact I have a module accessing behavior from the main entry point I am happy about and that I don't want to break but I would also like to use modules deeper in the folder tree as primary access points for some applications, which I currently have trouble with.

Comment: The `str.rpartition()` call splits on the last `.` and returns the first half; so `foo.bar.baz.eggs` splits off to `foo.bar.baz`. The rest is too broad to go into in comments.

Answer (score 55):

> ### All I want to know is what exactly does `__package__` mean

It is the mechanism that enables explicit relative imports.

There are three possible categories of values for `__package__`

- A package name (a string)
- An empty string
- None

#### Package Name

That is, if a module is in a package, `__package__` is set to the package name to enable explicit relative imports. [Specifically:](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__package__)

> When the module is a package, its `__package__` value should be set to its `__name__`. When the module is not a package, `__package__` should be set [...] for submodules, to the parent package’s name.

#### Empty String

If a module is at root, or top-level, that is, the current module is imported with

```
import current_module
```

or when a top-level module is run as the entry point as with:

```
$ python -m current_module
```

then `__package__` is an empty string. Or as the [documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__package__):

> When the module is not a package, `__package__` should be set to the empty string for top-level modules...

#### None

If a module/script is run by filename, [`__package__` is None](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/):

> When the main module is specified by its filename, then the `__package__` attribute will be set to None.

### Evidence

First, let's create a file structure with noisy debugging - using Python 3.6:

```
text = "print(f'{__name__}, __file__: {__file__}, __package__: {repr(__package__)}')"

from pathlib import Path
Path('foo.py').write_text(text)
Path('package').mkdir()
Path('package/__init__.py').write_text(text)
Path('package/__main__.py').write_text(text)
Path('package/bar.py').write_text(text)

# and include a submodule with a relative import:
Path('package/baz.py').write_text(text + '\nfrom . import bar')
```

Now we see that foo.py executed as a module has an empty string for `__package__`, while the script executed by file name as the entry point has `None`:

```
$ python -m foo
__main__, __file__: ~\foo.py, __package__: ''
$ python foo.py
__main__, __file__: foo.py, __package__: None
```

When we execute a package as a module for the entry point, its `__init__.py` module runs, then its `__main__.py` runs:

```
$ python -m package
package, __file__: ~\package\__init__.py, __package__: 'package'
__main__, __file__: ~\package\__main__.py, __package__: 'package'
```

Similarly, when we execute a submodule as a module for the entry point, the `__init__.py` module runs, then it runs:

```
$ python -m package.bar
package, __file__: ~\package\__init__.py, __package__: 'package'
__main__, __file__: ~\package\bar.py, __package__: 'package'
```

Finally, we see that the explicit relative import, the entire reason for having `__package__`, (which happens last here) is enabled:

```
$ python -m package.baz
package, __file__: ~\package\__init__.py, __package__: 'package'
__main__, __file__: ~\package\baz.py, __package__: 'package'
package.bar, __file__: ~\package\bar.py, __package__: 'package'
```

<sub>Note, in the output, I have substituted `~` for the parent directories.</sub>

Comment: I guess a small quirk is calling a package by its name like so: ```python package```. In that case ```__package__``` is `''` and not ```None```. Beats me why that is the choice though

Comment: I wonder if that's similar to the situation where running `foo.py` that indirectly imports itself as a script creates two modules (`__main__` and `foo`); running `package` executes `package/__main__.py`, but also creates the module `package`.