# dunder package attribute not returning the package name

Tags: python

Just wanted to get the package name of a given module, why does not the dunder **package** attribute work?

```
import sys, inspect, os, numpy as np
print("The os package name is " + os.__package__)
print("The np package name is " + np.__package__)
print("The inspect package name is " + inspect.__package__)
print("The sys package name is " + sys.__package__)
```

What I get from the above is as follows.

```
The os package name is 
The np package name is numpy
The inspect package name is 
The sys package name is
```

As you can see, it works only for numpy and does not work for others. Can someone enlighten me why? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [PEP366](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/)

Also check out this other StackOverflow post [whats-the-purpose-of-the-package-attribute-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233229/whats-the-purpose-of-the-package-attribute-in-python)