# Python module and package having the same name

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is an example of my project.

When running *foo.py* I get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo.bar'; 'foo' is not a package

Renaming the `foo/` directory or the `foo.py` file solves the problem, but I'd love to know if there is another way and why this is happening?

```
project/
        |
        foo/
        |  __init__.py
        |  foo.py
        |  bar.py
        |
        setup.py
```

> In foo.py

```
import foo.bar

    if __name__=='__main__':
       pass
```

Comment: The answer depends on what you mean by "when run foo.py"

You're going to need to clarify that. What did you do when you ran foo.py?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is likely how you're running `foo.py` as a script. If you run `python foo.py` from inside the `project/foo` directory, Python will assume that `foo.py` is a module at the global level, and that will prevent the `foo/` folder from being seen as a global package (even if `project/` is in the module search path). It would expect to import `bar.py` as `bar` at the top level too, rather than as a module within a `foo` package.

You can probably work around this issue by changing how you run `foo.py`. Instead of `python foo.py`, try `python -m foo.foo` (from the `project/` folder, if necessary).

It may also be possible to work around some of the issues by setting a `__package__` value in your modules (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21233334/1405065) for another answer explaining `__package__` and providing some useful links). That might only fix explicit relative imports between modules in the package though (so you could change `import foo.bar` to `from . import bar` and it would work), but I'm not sure if it can restore the `foo` package to its proper place in the global namespace (so other code outside the package might still break).