# Python: Switch from script mode to module mode

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-importlib

I have a complex repository structure with multiple sub-packages:

```
/foo/file1.py
/foo/file2.py
/foo/bar/file3.py
/common/shared.py
```

(very simplified version)

All package references are either explicitly relative or absolute from the root.
Everything works fine, but I need to run all scripts as modules using their full name from the root, e.g.: `python -m foo.file1`. The coding guideline for the repository is and will remain to use this pattern to run scripts.

Yet, is there a way to make a few files runnable as a script in this setup?

For example, I wish I could do:

```
if not __package__:
    __package__ = "foo.bar"

# use relative or absolute imports as if the file was run with python -m
```

I already tried `importlib` or `runpy` without success. Using `sys.path.append` makes absolute imports valid but relative imports are still an issue.

Comment: Maybe I don't get your question but, have you tried to add a `if __name__=="__main__":` to make your desired script runnable?

Comment: My goal is to create a very specific file that can be run as a script (`python file.py`) and still get imports to work properly. I know how to test that my module is the main. Also `__name__ == "__main__"` is true for both `python file.py` and `python -m file`.

Comment: Then I think that the first answer to this post is what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21233229/whats-the-purpose-of-the-package-attribute-in-python

Comment: I do not understand how this helps.