# Python import problem: Why is my python code unexpectedly trying to import a module function?

Tags: python, python-import

When I run my top-level file `downloader.py`, I'm getting an unexpected import error, unexpected since I thought the function is finished by the time `downloader.py` calls it. I'm not sure which file this is supposed to be resolved in. I'm running in VS Code and using the VS Code generated venv

```
from downloader_mod.shelf import ShelfData
  File "c:\archive_shelf_flaskbased\src\downloader_mod\shelf.py", line 6, in <module>
    from directory_handler import DirectoryNameHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'directory_handler'
```

When I run `shelf.py` directly, where the class is called, it runs fine.
When I ran `downloader.py` prior to adding the `DirectoryNameHandler()` call in the submodule it ran fine.

**File structure:**

```
archive_shelf_flaskbased/
  .vscode/
  src/
    [app.py] * to do
    [views.py] * to do
    downloader.py
    logging_config.py
    __init__.py
    downloader_mod/
        directory_handler.py
        download.py
        page.py
        shelf.py
        __init__.py
```

**What I tried:**

- I added `from downloader_mod.directory_handler import DirectoryNameHandler` to `downloader.py` it didn't make a difference.
- Added `__init__.py` to the `downloader_mod` folder. That also didn't make a difference.
- Ran from command line in venv with no effect

```
(venv) PS C:\archive_shelf_flaskbased\src> & "c:/Goodreads Bookshelf Tool/archive_shelf_flaskbased/venv/Scripts/python.exe" "c:/Goodreads Bookshelf Tool/archive_shelf_flaskbased/src/downloader.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\archive_shelf_flaskbased\src\downloader.py", line 3, in <module>
    from downloader_mod.shelf import ShelfData
  File "c:\archive_shelf_flaskbased\src\downloader_mod\shelf.py", line 6, in <module>     
    from directory_handler import DirectoryNameHandler
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'directory_handler'
```

**What I have NOT tried:**

- I have not tried modifying PYTHONPATH yet because I'm not sure that's the problem or the right setting to change. If it is, what needs to be added and where. Does it go in `.vscode/settings.json`, `.vscode/launch.json`, `.env`, or a command line change?

**File Code:**

src/downloader.py

```py
from downloader_mod.shelf import ShelfData
from downloader_mod.directory_handler import DirectoryNameHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
setup_logging()
sh = ShelfData({'shelf_name': "Generic", 'creation_date': "02/25/2023"})
sh.setup_download_dir()
print(f"{sh.simple_dir = }")
```

src/downloader_mod/shelf.py

```py
from directory_handler import DirectoryNameHandler

class ShelfData:
    def __init__(self, data_dict=None):
        self.initialize_shelf_dict()
        if data_dict is not None:
            self.add_data_to_shelf_dict(data_dict)
        # self.shelf_name and self.creation_date made above
        dn = DirectoryNameHandler(self.shelf_name, self.creation_date)
        self.simple_dir = dn.simple_dir
```

downloader_mod/directory_handler.py

```py
from datetime import datetime

class DirectoryNameHandler:
    def __init__(self, shelf_name, date_obj) -> None:
        year = f'{date_obj.year}'
        self.simple_dir = f"{shelf_name}_{date_obj.strftime('%b%d')}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run the script, only `src`, not `download_mod`, is on your module search path.

`shelf.py` should be using a *relative* import, instead of assuming that `directory_handler.py` is also a top-level module.

```
from .directory_handler import DirectoryNameHandler
```

Comment: I thought the `venv` was supposed to include subfolders of the project. Maybe it's venv/pyvenv.cfg where I need to add the path. Anyway, now I know it's an environment path problem and can work on it from there. Also, I didn't understand how the subfolder should call it's siblings. Thanks for clarity!

Comment: This was ONLY a *relative* import when `main.py` called `mod1/file1.py` which called `mod1/file2.py`. If I executed file1.py directly, the import didn't work. To fix it, I used a project config file and added the subfolders to `sys.path.insert (1, ...)` there. Other possibilities included 1) `pyvenv.cfg` (environment-specific), 2) VS Code `launch.json -> config:{env: ...}` (not portable?), 3) `$env:PATH += $env:PythonProjects` (machine-specific). 4) I chose `sys.path` for now.

Comment: To make relative imports work when you execute a file as a script, you need to set `__package__` to an appropriate value. See https://peps.python.org/pep-0366/#proposed-change for details.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that! I found this response that goes into further understanding `__package__` attribute:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48833828/9915864