# How to create python Ply lex passing a module

Tags: python, ironpython, lex, traceback, ply

I'm trying to use a Logo Language Compiler that uses Ply into the Unity3D environment for an Open Source project https://github.com/ssouzawallace/blocks-programming.

To do so I am using IronPython that is a Python interpreter running in .NET (I need this to run in Uinty3D). There is a bug in IronPython and i found others with the same issue related to the traceback of python script execution.

In resume if I run the Logo Compiler using the official Python interpreter everything goes OK. But in IronPython, when the code pass trough the `get_caller_module_dic` method it cannot find my pyLex stuff because it cannot reach the second frame level.

In order to resolve the problem I am wondering to pass the proper object or module to the method:

```
def lex(module=None,object=None,debug=0,optimize=0,lextab="lextab",reflags=0,nowarn=0,outputdir="", debuglog=None, errorlog=None):
```

But I don't know how to do this.

Someone know what can I do?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Found solution here [Python: How do I get a reference to a module inside the module itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676835/python-how-do-i-get-a-reference-to-a-module-inside-the-module-itself)

Now I pass the entire script as a module instead hoping the lex and yacc script find my module using the traceback.

Using

`import sys
current_module = sys.modules[__name__]`