# Executing a Button command from another file?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I have started working on a GUI system where I need to import a function from one file to be executed in the main file when a button is pressed, but every time I run it I get:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'Two' has no attribute 'sum'
  (most likely due to a circular import)
```

The program is supposed to input two values, `Value_a` and `Value_b`, and the function being called `sum()` is supposed to add the two and output a result in a new window. Here is an example of the file I want to import and its function `sum()`:

**`Two.py`**:

```
from tkinter import *  #Import the tkinter module    
import One #This is the main file, One.py

def sum():
    newWindow = Toplevel(One.Window)
    newWindow.title("Sum")
    a = int(One.Value_a.get())
    b = int(One.Value_b.get())
    c = a+b
    Label(newWindow, text= str(c)).grid(row=1, column=0)
```

This is how the main file looks like:

**`One.py`**:

```
from tkinter import *
import Two

Window = Tk()
Window.title("Main Window")

Value_a = Entry(Window, width=15).grid(row=1, column=0)
Value_b = Entry(Window, width=15).grid(row=2, column=0)
my_button = Button(Window, text="Test", command=lambda: Two.sum).grid(row=3, column=0)

Window.mainloop()
```

When this is run, I end up getting the above error.

Comment: Importing `One` inside `Two.py` will create another instance of `Tk` (`One.Window`), not using the instance of `Tk` (`Window`) when running `One.py`.  You need to pass `Window`, `Value_a` and `Value_b` to `Two.sum()` instead and don't import `One` inside `Two.py`.

Comment: @acw1668: It's not quite that easy. See answer I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you really do have a circular `import`. Module `One` imports module `Two` which imports module `One`... etc. However the simple fix @acw1668 suggested isn't enough to fix things because the `Two` module references more than just the `Window` attribute of the `One` module. My solution passes the things in module `One` the function in module `Two` needs as arguments (so the `Two` module doesn't need to `import` it to get access to them).

Another problem with your tkinter code is discussed in the question  [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) , which I suggest you read.

Below are changes to both your modules that fix all these issues.

**`One.py`:**

```
from tkinter import *
import Two


Window = Tk()
Window.title("Main Window")

Value_a = Entry(Window, width=15)
Value_a.grid(row=1, column=0)
Value_b = Entry(Window, width=15)
Value_b.grid(row=2, column=0)

my_button = Button(Window, text="Test",
                   command=lambda: Two.sum(Window, Value_a, Value_b))
my_button.grid(row=3, column=0)

Window.mainloop()
```

**`Two.py`:**

```
from tkinter import *


def sum(Window, Value_a, Value_b):
    newWindow = Toplevel(Window)
    newWindow.title("Sum")
    a = int(Value_a.get())
    b = int(Value_b.get())
    c = a+b
    Label(newWindow, text= str(c)).grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Comment: I would prefer using class in `One.py` and pass the instance of the class to `Two.sum()`.

Comment: @acw1668: That would work of course, but it would be even simpler to simply pass multiple arguments to `sum()`.

Comment: @acw1668: Since it's so much simpler, I've modified my answer to do it like that — the whole `sys.modules` approach was just too weird…

Comment: Although it is simpler, but if later `Two.sum()` needs to refer another widget then the function definition is required to be changed.  Your original design (or my suggestion of using class instance) need not to change the definition of `Two.sum()`, only need to change the content of the function.

Comment: @martineau: Thanks for the solution. The program works as I wanted it thanks to your adjustment on the code. Thanks.

Comment: @acw1668: After a little research, I decided passing the module wasn't too unusual and found a slightly better way of getting a reference to it — see the other answer I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

**<sub>(Here's another answer which is very similar to what I initially had in my other answer before doing something I felt was simpler. I'm posting it as separate answer because it turns out that the [idea of a module getting a reference to itself has been around for a very long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676835/how-to-get-a-reference-to-a-module-inside-the-module-itself), so doing so isn't that weird or as hackish as I initially thought.)</sub>**

The problem is because you really do have a circular `import`. Module `One` imports module `Two` which imports module `One`... etc. However the simple fix @acw1668 suggested isn't enough to fix things because the `Two` module references more than just the `Window` attribute of the `One` module. My solution passes the *whole* `One` module to the function as an argument (so the `Two` module doesn't need to `import` it to get access to its attributes).

Another problem with your tkinter code is discussed in the question  [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name) , which I suggest you read.

Below are changes to both your modules that fix all these issues. To avoid the circular import, the Button command now passes the calling module as an argument to the `sum()` function in module `Two`. While doing something like this *is* somewhat unusual, in fact is a very logical if you think about it (and want to avoid a circular import`).

**`One.py`:**

```
from tkinter import *
import Two

CURRENT_MODULE = __import__(__name__)

Window = Tk()
Window.title("Main Window")

Value_a = Entry(Window, width=15)
Value_a.grid(row=1, column=0)
Value_b = Entry(Window, width=15)
Value_b.grid(row=2, column=0)

my_button = Button(Window, text="Test", command=lambda: Two.sum(CURRENT_MODULE))
my_button.grid(row=3, column=0)

Window.mainloop()
```

**`Two.py`:**

```
from tkinter import *

def sum(One):
    newWindow = Toplevel(One.Window)
    newWindow.title("Sum")
    a = int(One.Value_a.get())
    b = int(One.Value_b.get())
    c = a+b
    Label(newWindow, text= str(c)).grid(row=1, column=0)
```